# Groovy pipe in sh execution

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to write a goofy script to return all of the branches in a given remote git repo. When I run the following from the command line:

```
git ls-remote --refs git ls-remote --refs https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy.git | cut -f2
```

I see a bunch of branches:

```
refs/heads/1.0.x
refs/heads/1.1.x
refs/heads/master
refs/pull/1/head
refs/pull/100/head
refs/pull/100/merge
refs/pull/1001/head
refs/pull/1001/merge
refs/pull/1006/head
refs/pull/1006/merge
refs/pull/1007/head
refs/pull/1007/merge
refs/pull/1008/head
refs/pull/101/head
refs/pull/101/merge
refs/pull/1016/head
refs/pull/1016/merge
...
```

However, when I attempt to run this from groovy with the following:

```
"git ls-remote --refs https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy.git | cut -f2".execute().text.tokenize()
```

I get an empty set:

```
[]
```

I'm not sure if the issue is with the pipe in the command or not but my groovy noob fiddling seems to be pointing in that direction. I have seen some comments about using pipes in groovy commands but they don't seem to be similar to what I am trying to achieve. Ultimately, I am trying to feed the [Extensible Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin) for Jenkins. :)

EDIT:

I understand that several people think this is a duplicate. However, I am having a hard time using any of the linked examples to collect and tokenize the results. I have tried several variations including:

```
def lns = "git ls-remote --refs https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy.git".execute() | "cut -f2".execute()
lns.waitFor()

println lns
```

This results in:

```
$ groovy gitstuff.groovy
java.lang.UNIXProcess@4f6ee6e4
```

I then tried to cast to text and tokenize:

```
def lns = "git ls-remote --refs https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy.git".execute() | "cut
-f2".execute() lns.waitFor().text.tokenize() println lns
```

This results in an error due to the fact that I am getting some non-string values:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: text for class: java.lang.Integer
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: text for class: java.lang.Integer
    at gitstuff.run(gitstuff.groovy:2)
```

I'm not too familiar with the collect logic in groovy to filter this. Regardless, I have not been successful converting the linked answer to my scenario where I have a list being returns that needs to be tokenized.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question worked for me.

Comment: @doelleri You are able to do that and tokenize the results to return as a list? I have been trying to play with different versions of it for over an hour now and it either hangs or errors-out.

Comment: Do `lns.waitFor()` first then separately `lns.text.tokenize()`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got that working but now I can't get it back to the Jenkins Extensible Parameter plugin. Progress though so thank you!